# While executing mysql insert select query- can we do condition check?

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to execute mysql select insert query as below.

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS.TABLE1 (NAME,ID,STARTTIME,ENDTIME) SELECT NAME,ID,CREATIONTIME,EXPIRYTIME FROM ACCOUNTS.TABLE2 WHERE ...;
```

Now, if EXPIRYTIME in table2 is null, then i want to update the ENDTIME in table1 to current timestamp. I have overriden the default behavior of this timestamp field by the description

```
ENDTIME TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

for some reason.

Is it possible in the above select insert query to include some something like an if condition saying if (expirytime == null) then update endtime to current timestamp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select what you want:

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS.TABLE1 (NAME,ID,STARTTIME,ENDTIME) 
SELECT NAME,ID,CREATIONTIME, ifnull(EXPIRYTIME, now())
FROM ACCOUNTS.TABLE2 WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS.TABLE1 (NAME,ID,STARTTIME,ENDTIME) 
SELECT NAME,ID,CREATIONTIME,if(EXPIRYTIME is null,now(),expirytime) 
FROM ACCOUNTS.TABLE2 WHERE ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a insert [trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to do that?